# VlookUP whole column with variables

Tags: excel, vba

Id like to skip loops, because the file I use has around 10k rows. Id like to use vlookup using two diffrent workbooks. I will provide only a part of my code, but I get the error by the vlookup. The error is Error 438"Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method. Firstly user hat to choose a file because it is diffrent every month. The we get the file names oldbpm. Then it is just about to ser the number of columns. File BPM-Tool is the one where I run a macro. Ask if You need any other information. 
Another thing is if it works then with autofill.

```
Dim Sheetstarybpm As Worksheet
Dim myrange As Range
Dim countrowsoldbpm1 As Long
Dim countrowsoldbpm As Long

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select BPM Report for previous month"
        .ButtonName = "OK"
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show

        oldbpm = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
End With


    Workbooks.Open oldbpm

    Set Sheetstarybpm = ActiveSheet

    countrowsoldbpm1 = Range("a10", Range("a10").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Set myrange = Range("A10:CW" & countrowsoldbpm1)

Workbooks("BPM-Tool.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("OU").Activate

    countrowsoldbpm = Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Range("D1").Formula "=VLOOKUP(B2,'[" & oldbpm & "]" & Sheetstarybpm & "'!" & myrange & ",100,FALSE))"
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D" & countrowsoldbpm)

End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbooks("BPM PAC Report_04-2019_CONTRACT PROJECTS_FINAL_AD_ADM.xlsm").Open` - that's not how you open a workbook. See the [`Workbooks.Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) documentation. Also, get rid of the `On Error Resume Next`. It's just hiding potential errors.

Comment: I changed the line to workbooks.open oldbpm. With the On Error Resume Next what to do If the macro doesnt find the value?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "find the value"? I'm not sure what value you're referring to. It just looks like you're writing a formula to the sheet.

Comment: I mean Id like to find the costs of a project with the projects code. so in every row starting with B2 we have this code. Id like to find same code in another workook and then the value 100 columnd on the right.